# Google Sheets Script - Copying data range from one sheet to another - whole range not copying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Bit of a rookie at this and learning atm. I am using the following script to copy data from one sheet to another in the same Google spreadsheet:

```js
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cover");
  var source = sheet.getRange("a1:c21");
  var values = source.getValues();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("January 2020")
  values [0] [0] = new Date();
  sheet2.appendRow(values [0])
}
```

Which works fine to copy a single row but does not copy the entire range listed (a1:c21). Now I imagine the problem lies around Row 8 but I am not sure.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet I am using for trying this out:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pEbNy-PmrGeAmpASRUK2iXIyJPfg43Mm2r6bbiTBuM/edit#gid=1296663899

Comment: Your issue lies with your `.appendRow()`, you're only adding **one** row of data by using `values[0]`.

Comment: Thought so, so what would be the alternative? If you add values [1] then it copies row 2 and nothing else. What do you add there to copy the entire range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cover");
  var source = sheet.getRange("a1:c21");
  var values = source.getValues();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("January 2020")
  values [0][0] = new Date();
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you very much. Spot on. So I understand moving forward;

The '.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1'  finds the available space on the second sheet,

Then '1,values.length,values[0].length)' tells it what the full range of the data is and to the next available space? The [0] denoting to start from the first row? 

Finally the .setValues(values) actually inputs the data? 

Want to make sure I understand how it works rather than simply copying the answer. As I said I am a rookie at this so its a whole new area of understanding. (YouTube, Google and Stackoverflow learning)